# How to click a column to switch pages in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Im new to flutter and im creating a carwash pos app. I've finished coding my home page but i dont get how can i switch to another page with the user clicking on one of the columns/boxes

[image: this is the ui, the user should click on one of the categories and be redirected on the next page]

here is the code for the categories section

```
  Column _categoriesSection() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          child: Text(
            'Services Category',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 120,
          child: ListView.separated(
            itemCount: categories.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(
              width: 25,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: categories[index].boxColor.withOpacity(0.3),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(categories[index].iconPath),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        categories[index].name,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => CategoryPage(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

here is the code for the main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'pages/home_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Heavelock Titling'),
        home: const HomePage());
  }
}
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'pages/home_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Heavelock Titling'),
        home: const HomePage());
  }
}
```

and the code for the entire home_page.dart with the categories section as shown above

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:mapp32/models/category_model.dart';
import 'package:mapp32/models/popular_model.dart';
import 'package:mapp32/models/recom_model.dart';
import 'category_page.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<CategoryModel> categories = [];
  List<RecomModel> recom = [];
  List<PopularServicesModel> popularServices = [];

  void _getInitialInfo() {
    categories = CategoryModel.getCategories();
    recom = RecomModel.getRecom();
    popularServices = PopularServicesModel.getPopularServices();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _getInitialInfo();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          _searchField(),
          const SizedBox(height: 40),
          _categoriesSection(),
          const SizedBox(height: 40),
          _recomSection(),
          const SizedBox(height: 40),
          _popularServicesSection(),
          const SizedBox(height: 40),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Column _popularServicesSection() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          child: Text(
            'Popular',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 15),
        ListView.separated(
          itemCount: popularServices.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(height: 25),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 20,
            right: 20,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: popularServices[index].boxIsSelected
                    ? Colors.white
                    : Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                boxShadow: popularServices[index].boxIsSelected
                    ? [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: const Color(0xff1D1617).withOpacity(0.07),
                          offset: const Offset(0, 10),
                          blurRadius: 40,
                          spreadRadius: 0,
                        ),
                      ]
                    : [],
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    popularServices[index].iconPath,
                    width: 65,
                    height: 65,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        popularServices[index].name,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '${recom[index].duration}|${recom[index].price}',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff7B6F72),
                          fontSize: 13,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/icons/button.svg',
                      width: 30,
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Column _recomSection() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          child: Text(
            'Recommendation\nFor You',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 15),
        SizedBox(
          height: 240,
          child: ListView.separated(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                width: 210,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: recom[index].boxColor.withOpacity(0.3),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                      recom[index].iconPath,
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          recom[index].name,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '${recom[index].duration}|${recom[index].price}',
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xff7B6F72),
                            fontSize: 13,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 45,
                      width: 130,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              recom[index].viewIsSelected
                                  ? const Color(0xff9DCEFF)
                                  : Colors.transparent,
                              recom[index].viewIsSelected
                                  ? const Color(0xff92A3FD)
                                  : Colors.transparent,
                            ],
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'View',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: recom[index].viewIsSelected
                                ? Colors.white
                                : const Color(0xffC58BF2),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(width: 25),
            itemCount: recom.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 20,
              right: 20,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Column _categoriesSection() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          child: Text(
            'Services Category',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 120,
          child: ListView.separated(
            itemCount: categories.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(
              width: 25,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: categories[index].boxColor.withOpacity(0.3),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(categories[index].iconPath),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        categories[index].name,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => CategoryPage(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Container _searchField() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 20, right: 20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            color: const Color(0xff1D1617).withOpacity(0.11),
            blurRadius: 40,
            spreadRadius: 0.0)
      ]),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            hintText: 'Search Services',
            hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xffDDDADA), fontSize: 14),
            prefixIcon: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
              child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/Search.svg'),
            ),
            suffixIcon: SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    const VerticalDivider(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      indent: 10,
                      endIndent: 10,
                      thickness: 0.1,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/Filter.svg'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                borderSide: BorderSide.none)),
      ),
    );
  }

  AppBar appBar() {
    return AppBar(
      title: const Text(
        'Angel\'s Carwash',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0.0,
      centerTitle: true,
      leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xffF7F8F8),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/icons/Arrow - Left 2.svg',
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 37,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xffF7F8F8),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/icons/dots.svg',
              height: 5,
              width: 5,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

lastly the screen i want to switch to category_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';


class CategoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategoryPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CategoryPage> createState() => _CategoryPageState();
}

class _CategoryPageState extends State<CategoryPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: ListView(
        children: const [],
      ),
    );
  }

  AppBar appBar() {
    return AppBar(
      title: const Text(
        'Angel\'s Carwash',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0.0,
      centerTitle: true,
      leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xffF7F8F8),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/icons/Arrow - Left 2.svg',
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 37,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xffF7F8F8),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/icons/dots.svg',
              height: 5,
              width: 5,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change `category_page()` to `CategoryPage()` :

```
onTap: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => CategoryPage(), // Use CategoryPage instead of category_page()
    ),
  );
},
```

Comment: category_screen is a statefulwidget screen with category_screen.dart, i tried importing it but it cant seem to recognize the call when i navigate

Comment: try to change the class name from category_screen to CategoryScreen, if the issue is still there, please provide class code, so people can review it and help you.

Comment: i did what you said and i got another error highlighting on the CategoryPage(), saying "1 positional argument expected by 'CategoryPage.new', but 0 found. Try adding the missing argument."

Comment: @HiI'mJustin if you still have the issue, first try to change "const CategoryPage({super.key});" to "const CategoryPage({Key? key}): super(key: key);", and if error still there means probably you didnt provide the full CategoryPage class or you added an argument in the constructor, well the error suggests that the class expects some arguments in its constructor.